Как передавать данные из MainViewModel в UserControlViewModel?
Есть главный экран, в нем по кнопке переключаются UserControl'ы.
По кнопке все прекрасно отображается, но в модели Simatic существует массив, который нужно отображать и передавать в CharViewModel, где по изменению значения Slider отображается на графике определенная часть массива.
В модели Simatic.TranslatedCoord данные могут измениться в любое время и нужно их передать в CharViewModel.
P.S. Была мысль передавать полностью экземпляр Simatic, но все его данные не нужны, а только координаты.
XAML MainView:
<! -- Кнопки переключения UserControl -->
<Button Content="График"    Command="{Binding CmdSelectChart}"   />
<Button Content="Модель"    Command="{Binding CmdSelectModel3D}" />
<Button Content="Фото"      Command="{Binding CmdSelectPhoto}"   />
<Button Content="Настройки" Command="{Binding CmdSelectSetting}" /> 

<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SelectWindow}" />

MainViewModel.cs:
private AppSetting appsetting;
private Simatic simatic;
private object selectWindow;
private ObservableCollection<object> selectWindowList;

private CharUserControl charUserControl;
private Model3DUserControl model3UserControl;
private PhotoUserControl photoUserControl;
private SettingUserControl settingUserControl;

private ICommand cmdSelectChart, cmdSelectModel3D, cmdSelectPhoto, cmdSelectSetting;


// Поля класса
public Simatic Simatic
{
    get => simatic;
}

public object SelectWindow
{
    get => selectWindow;
    set
    {
        selectWindow = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectWindow");
    }
}

// Команды
public ICommand CmdSelectChart
{
     get => cmdSelectChart;
}
// и т.д. для ICommand


public MainViewModel()
{

    appsetting = SettingReader();
    simatic = new Simatic(appsetting.Simatic);
    
    // ...
    
    charUserControl = new CharUserControl(appsetting.Measurement, simatic.TranslatedCoord);
    model3UserControl = new Model3DUserControl(appsetting.Measurement);
    photoUserControl = new PhotoUserControl(appsetting.Photo);
    settingUserControl = new SettingUserControl();
    
    selectWindowList = new ObservableCollection<object> 
    { 
       charUserControl, 
       model3UserControl, 
       photoUserControl, 
       settingUserControl 
    };

    // Инициализируем действия кнопок
    cmdSelectChart = new DelegateCommand((o) => SelectWindow = selectWindowList[0]);
    cmdSelectModel3D = new DelegateCommand((o) => SelectWindow = selectWindowList[1]);
    cmdSelectPhoto = new DelegateCommand((o) => SelectWindow = selectWindowList[2]);
    cmdSelectSetting = new DelegateCommand((o) => SelectWindow = selectWindowList[3]);

}

XAML CharUserControl:
<Slider Value="{Binding SliderValue, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionStart="0" Minimum="0" Maximum="{Binding MaxSliderValue}" TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" IsSelectionRangeEnabled="True" />

<lvc:CartesianChart DockPanel.Dock="Top" DisableAnimations="True" LegendLocation="Top">
    <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
            <lvc:LineSeries Values="{Binding ModelCharts, Mode=OneWay}" StrokeThickness="1.5" Stroke="Green" LineSmoothness="0" />
        </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
</lvc:CartesianChart>

CharViewModel:
private MeasurementSetting setting;
private Charts charts;
private ChartValues<ObservablePoint> modelCharts;
private double[,] coordinates;
private int sliderValue;

public int SliderValue
{
    get => sliderValue;
        set
        {
            sliderValue = value;
            SliderValueUpdateData(sliderValue);
            OnPropertyChanged("SliderValue");
        }
}

public ChartValues<ObservablePoint> ModelCharts
{
    get => modelCharts;
        private set
        {
            modelCharts = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ModelCharts");
        }
}

public double[,] Coordinates
{
    get => coordinates;
        set
        {
            coordinates = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Coordinates");
        }
}

public CharViewModel(MeasurementSetting setting, double[,] coordinates)
{
    this.setting = setting;
    this.coordinates = coordinates;

    charts = new Charts(setting.PointCount, setting.PointDistance);
}

private void SliderValueUpdateData(int value)
{
    if (coordinates != null)
            ModelCharts = charts.Draw(value, coordinates);
    else
            ModelCharts = charts.EmptyPoints();
}


Вся ваша логика с charUserControl = new CharUserControl...SelectWindow = selectWindowList[0] - это очень грубое нарушение MVVM, ибо он создан специально, чтоб отделить UI от данных, а вы вот так грубо в VM слое создаете View слои. Так что, у вас сейчас нету MVVM. Далее "данные могут измениться в любое время" - ну так сделайте там событие "данные обновились" и передавайте при помощи этого события хоть все данные, хоть обновленную часть, а в нужной VM подписывайтесь на данное событие (ну или за пределами VM подписывайтесь и по событию дергайте метод конкретной VM).

Хорошо, тогда подскажите пожалуйста как правильно реализовать по MVVM переключение UserControl'ов.

По правилам MVVM вы не должны знать ничего про UI, как и UI не должен ничего знать про другие слои. Это ключевое. Исходя из этого, вы должны оперировать VM, а не контроами. Скажем, у вас есть страница главная (Home), под нее UI (View) в виде контрола (пусть будет HomePage), под нее также должна быть своя VM (HomePageViewModel), ну и переключение у вас будет CurrentPage = new HomePageViewModel(). Об этом способе рассказано в этом ответе.

@EvgeniyZ Правильно ли я понял - в MainView реализую поля класса ViewModel, затем в App.xaml передаю их в View DataContext из MainViewModel? Затем в MainView создаю DataTemplate и ContentPresenter. Далее Simatic добавляю Action по изменению координат, и по его срабатыванию в MainViewModel передаю в поле класса Char.Coordinates?

Я вам говорю "не должны знать", а вы мне "в View реализую поля ViewModel"... Еще раз повторю, вы не должны в VM хранить что-то связанное с View, а в View у вас не должно быть чего либо связанного с VM.

@EvgeniyZ Извините, печатался. В MainViewModel реализую поля ViewModel UserControl'ов, а за тем в App.xaml и далее по тексту.

В App.xaml.cs у вас должно быть что-то по типу new MainWindow { DataContext = new MainViewModel() }.Show();, можете туда передать что-то еще если надо, это будет вашей стартовой точкой приложения. Дальше DataContext вообще не трогаете, все WPF вам сам подставит. Остальное да, +- все так. Я буквально вчера давал такой ответ, посмотрите там часть про UI в самом низу, там как раз 2 отдельные VM которые по событию оповещают главную VM, которая в свою очередь делает что надо, вот что-то такое у вас должно быть.

@EvgeniyZ Понял, спасибо за ответ!

У меня есть проект на авалонии, я создал модель данных и передавал эту модель при переходе на другую страничку
Мой model:
 public class LabelData : ViewModelBase
    {
        private string? _title = String.Empty;
        public string? Title
        {
            get => _title;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _title, value);
        }
     }

Мой VM:
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private LabelData _description;
    private ViewModelBase _currentPageViewModel;
    public ViewModelBase CurrentPageViewModel
    {
        get => _currentPageViewModel;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _currentPageViewModel, value);
    }
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _description = new LabelData();
        CurrentPageViewModel = new LoginViewModel(this, _description);
    }
    public void NavigateBackToLogin()
    {
        TransitionDirection = true;
        CurrentPageViewModel = new LoginViewModel(this, _description);
    }
}

И VM странички логина:
public class LoginViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private MainWindowViewModel _mainWindowViewModel;
    private LabelData _labelData;
    public LoginViewModel(MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel, LabelData labelData)
    {
        _mainWindowViewModel = mainWindowViewModel;
        _labelData = labelData;
        LoginCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(ToLabelList);
    }
 }

И получить данные можно так string? Title => _labelData.Title;

Спасибо за предоставленный вариант решения! Решил задачу с используя DataContext и ContentPresenter. Все оказалось достаточно просто :)
